# Split with new line and store in datastructure

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I have text file data like :

> 2,2,1
>
> data1,123,89,1
> data2,124,90,2
> data3,125,91,3
> data4,126,92,4
>
> data5,127,93,5
> data6,128,94,6
> data7,129,95,7
>
> data8,130,96,8
> data9,131,97,9
> data10,132,98,10

The first line 2,2,1 indicate 2 lines from 1st set of lines and store it in nodeFile, 2 lines from 2nd set of lines store it in linkFile and 1 line from 3rd set of lines store it in moduleFile. However for example purpose I have shows small number of lines but its a larger file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadFile {
    static List<String> moduleFile = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> linkFile = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> nodeFile = new ArrayList<>();
    static int a[];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file11 = new File("/home/madhu/Desktop/node.txt");
        Scanner scAll = null;
        try {
            scAll = new Scanner(file11);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] numberOfLines = (scAll.nextLine()).split(",");

        int flag = 0;
        int counter = 1;
        while (scAll.hasNext()) {
            if (flag == 0 && "\\n\\n".equals(scAll.nextLine()) && counter <= Integer.parseInt(numberOfLines[0].trim())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(numberOfLines[0].trim()); i++) {
                    System.out.println(scAll.nextLine());
                    nodeFile.add(scAll.nextLine());
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter > Integer.parseInt(numberOfLines[0].trim())) {
                    flag = 1;
                    counter = 1;
                }

            } else if (flag == 1 && "\\n\\n".equals(scAll.nextLine())
                && counter <= Integer.parseInt(numberOfLines[1].trim())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(numberOfLines[1].trim()); i++) {
                    System.out.println(scAll.nextLine());
                    linkFile.add(scAll.nextLine());
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter > Integer.parseInt(numberOfLines[1].trim())) {
                    flag = 2;
                    counter = 1;
                }

                } else if (flag == 2 && "\\n\\n".equals(scAll.nextLine())
                && counter <= Integer.parseInt(numberOfLines[2].trim())) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(numberOfLines[2].trim()); i++) {
                    System.out.println(scAll.nextLine());
                    moduleFile.add(scAll.nextLine());
                    counter++;
                }

            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        scAll.close();


    }


    }
```

I have written the above code, but this code gets terminated during execution. How to get the desired result? Please help.

Comment: Can you see any errors when it's terminated?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am not misunderstanding, but this is what I'd do.

I didn't check to see if this is fully working example, but it should work more or less.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class ReadFile {
    // basically just do what you did
    static List<String> nodeFile;
    static List<String> linkFile;
    static List<String> moduleFile;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final File file = new File("/home/madhu/Desktop/node.txt");
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        // make it a little better for indexing
        final List<Integer> selections = Arrays
                .stream(scanner.nextLine().split(","))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // this is the meat of the code
        // basically each split up block of lines is a block
        final List<List<String>> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            while (!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("\n")) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
            if (!lines.isEmpty()) {
                blocks.add(lines);
            }
        }

        // allocate your files now
        nodeFile = blocks.get(0).subList(0, selections.get(0));
        linkFile = blocks.get(1).subList(0, selections.get(1));
        moduleFile = blocks.get(2).subList(0, selections.get(2));

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: while (!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("\n"))  i am getting error at this line. error : No line found .Can you please check @Allics

Comment: Ah yes, sorry @Madhusmita Sahoo. You'll want to do something like: `while (scanner.hasNextLine() && !(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("\n")) {` on that line instead.

Comment: hiii,  I am getting error : Index 1 out of bounds for length 1 at linkFile = blocks.get(1).subList(0, selections.get(1));  Can you please check @Aliics

Comment: This would probably mean that the blank lines are not just a simple new line character. You might want to confirm this by printing out the contents of `blocks`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code , i use **BufferedReader** because its more cleaner :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFile {

    static List<String> moduleFile = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> linkFile = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> nodeFile = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("/home/madhu/Desktop/node.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String data[] = reader.readLine().split(",");
            String s;
            int nbline=0, i=0,block =0;
            while ((s = reader.readLine())!=null && block < data.length) {
                if(s.equals("")){ 
                    block++;
                    nbline = Integer.parseInt(data[block-1]);
                    i = 0;
                }
                for(;i<nbline;i++){
                    s = reader.readLine();
                    if(s == null) break;
                    else if(s.equals("")){
                        block++;
                        break;
                    }
                    switch(block){
                        case 1 :
                            nodeFile.add(s);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            linkFile.add(s);
                            break;
                        default: moduleFile.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getStackTrace());
        } 
        finally{
            closeReader(reader);
        }
        
        System.out.println("nodeFile : "+nodeFile);
        System.out.println("linkFile : "+linkFile);
        System.out.println("moduleFile : "+moduleFile);
    }

    public static void closeReader(BufferedReader reader) {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

output :

```
nodeFile : [data1,123,89,1, data2,124,90,2]
linkFile : [data5,127,93,5, data6,128,94,6]
moduleFile : [data8,130,96,8]
```

Comment: One more help ! if i want to store nodeFile data to string array like String st[1] = data1,123,89,1, and st[2] =data2,124,90,2 . Hw can i do this because while splitting it also taking [ ]

Comment: Simply write `String st1 = nodeFile.toArray()`  and please consider accepting answer, if it was helpful